# Round Robin vs Co-operative Scheduling

Tags: scheduling, round-robin

I went through these two scheduling and only difference I find is that RR runs a task within a particular time, which means the current running task can he stopped and CPU is given to another task. Whereas, in co-operative, a task runs until it gives up its CPU time.

My understanding, is it right? Is there any other difference to it?

Answer (score 1):

Round-robin scheduling and cooperative scheduling [are not mutually exclusive](http://aigamedev.com/open/article/round-robin-multi-tasking/). Round-robin is simply another scheduling algorithm--the *most common* of which is [preemptive scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking#preemptivee_multitasking).

In **preemptive scheduling**, all tasks are given a set time limit. If a tasks uses up all its time, the task gets "kicked out" by the scheduler, who then decides if/how that tasks gets scheduled again.

With **cooperative scheduling**, the tasks themselves are written in such a way that they "cooperate" with each other, yielding execution when necessary.

Round robin schedulers can do both in a circularly-sequential manner.